# How to protect the shop via htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, shopware

I wanted to protect a Shopware 6 installation with a htaccess auth protection. But when i set it up in the `.htaccess` file in the `/public` folder i always get a "htaccess loop" in the backend (after login) and i can't use it anymore.

I tried to exclude `/api` and `/admin` but i am not happy with that.
How can i solve the problem?

**/public/.htaccess**

```
AuthName "Prompt"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/my-project/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "(/admin)" ALLOW
SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "(/api)" ALLOW

<RequireAny>
  Require env ALLOW
  Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```

Comment: `i always get a "htaccess loop" in the backend` Where exactly do you get this error?

Comment: Hi. I get it during the login process. i edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: There is no error called `htaccess loop` and there are no rewrite rules shown in your code. Are you getting this error from your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this at the beginning of your `public/.htaccess` file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please login."
AuthUserFile /home/my-project/.htpasswd

<RequireAny>
    Require expr %{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#.*?\s+\/api.*?#
    Require valid-user
</RequireAny>

// Rest goes here -->
```

https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-4243 (German)

Basic translation for non-german users:

> **Ticket: NEXT-4243 | auth_basic entry blocks backend access**
>
> This ticket is not intended for implementation. Therefore it was closed. Reasons that lead to such a decision can include the complexity or the scope of the ticket, as well as possible sources of error caused by the changes.
> [...]
> The short-term solution here is not to create the authentication through the hosting configuration, but to create it via htaccess / htpasswd and then not subject requests to the URL "/ api" to the authentication in the htaccess

Comment: your solution does not work :'(